# opencv MAT multiplication tips (java)

Tags: opencv, processing, mat

I am trying to make a simple mat multiplication (following this [example](http://www.widecodes.com/CxVjjgXekq/unable-to-multiply-matrix-in-opencv-java.html)) but it is giving me a very strange error. I am implementing this on processing IDE by the way.

```
import gab.opencv.*;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Core;

OpenCV opencv;

void setup(){
  size(300,300);
  opencv = new OpenCV(this, width, height);

  Mat r = new Mat(1, 3, CvType.CV_32F);
  r.put(0, 0, 0.707);
  r.put(0, 1, -0.707);
  r.put(1, 0, 0.707);
  r.put(1, 1, 0.707);

  Mat v = new Mat(1, 2, CvType.CV_32F);
  double d1 = 1.00;
  double d2 = 2.00;
  v.put(0, 0, d1);
  v.put(0, 1, d2);
  Mat final_mat = new Mat();

  Core.gemm(v,r,1,new Mat(),0,final_mat);

}
```

this is getting me an error at the Core.gemm line:
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (a_size.width == len) in gemm, file /Users/matthewepler/opencv-2.4.5/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp, line 718

what is this directory???

---

Can I use another method to multiply mat objects?

My original goal is to making something like this to work:

```
Mat C = ( A.t() * A ).inv(1) * ( A.t() * B );
```

Where A and B are the Mat I want to multiply...

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had mentioned it. I have edited the post including the error lines

Answer (score 1):

Well. It is my first time using mat, and I just followed an example.

But the thing is that Mat shape must follow some rules. See, Mat1.col and Mat2.row must match, or vice-versa. But I would like to hear if there is another(faster) way to do it.

```
import gab.opencv.*;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Core;


OpenCV opencv;

void setup(){
  size(300,300);
  opencv = new OpenCV(this, width, height);

  Mat r = new Mat(2, 3, CvType.CV_32FC1);
  r.put(0, 0, 0.707);
  r.put(0, 1, -0.707);
  r.put(1, 0, 0.707);
  r.put(1, 1, 0.707);

  Mat v = new Mat(2, 3, CvType.CV_32FC1);
  v.put(0, 0, 0.707);
  v.put(0, 1, -0.707);
  v.put(1, 0, 0.707);
  v.put(1, 1, 0.707);
  v.put(2, 0, 0.707);
  v.put(2, 1, 0.707);


  Mat A = new Mat();
  Mat B = new Mat();
  Mat C = new Mat();

  //C = ( At * A ).inv() * ( At * B ):
  Core.gemm(r.t(),r,1,new Mat(),0,A);
  Core.gemm(r.t(),v,1,new Mat(),0,B);
  Core.gemm(A.inv(),B,1,new Mat(),0,C);

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by faster? How would you multiply matrices if the columns in the first matrix did not match the rows in the second?